# Htaccess Static Root And wordpress Subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

Hello i have static html site in the root folder ex: www.example.com . and WordPress site in sub-folder ex: www.example.com/blog so where to put htaccess file in root or subfolder. and how to configure single htaccess file to work for both site.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you have in this htaccess file. If it's the Wordpress file, put it in the subfolder.

Anyway, you can have an htaccess file in both directory, the one in the subfolder will ovveride any file in parents directories.

Comment: thanks for replying and as for your reply in root htaccess file RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
and in subfolder htaccess file
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Well, this seems to have nothing to do with Wordpress, this is your root htaccess. Wordpress should create an htaccess in his subfolder, and you may need to customize it to set the rewrite base to /blog

Comment: can i control both root site and subfolder site in single htaccess.

Comment: Yes you can, but it may be easier to use the Wordpress htaccess as it is in its own directory